# Does javascript distinguish dash sign?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I use test.tested-by, the javascript reports -by is undefined. I am sure test contains tested-by property. Any solution here?

Comment: See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties and http://mothereff.in/js-properties#tested-by :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `test['tested-by']` instead. tested-by looks like tested minus by

Comment: Best practice is often to avoid it. I like the `.` syntax better, but this is correct.

Comment: See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties and http://mothereff.in/js-properties#tested-by :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
test["tested-by"]
```

This way you can provide any property name, even reserved keywords (like "class").

Answer (score 1):

See another question here: [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Basically, a - is not a valid variable character in javascript.

The `-` character is also not a valid `IdentifierName` character, which means you cannot use the dot notation. `test.tested-by` does not access the property `tested-by`. (You can use `test['tested-by']`.)

Comment: This has little to do with variable names, but rather with property names. The rules are similar but not exactly the same: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties

Comment: From that site: `Dot notation can only be used when the property name is a valid identifier name.` And that's what you are trying to do in your question.

Comment: Not my question (I am not the OP). Anyway, variable names in JavaScript are `Identifier`s, not `IdentifierName`s (which is the grammar that applies to property names). You’re confusing the two. `Identifier`s are `IdentifierName`s that are not `ReservedWord`s. For example, `var default;` throws a `SyntaxError`, while `var object = { default: 42 };` is fine as per the spec. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers for more info. In other words, your answer is correct, but it’s not the answer to OP’s question.

Comment: Or it does answer the question but uses incorrect terminology which can get confusing. So I updated my answer.